# WebBrowser control: show to user when it's navigating

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm developing a Windows Phone application.

I'm using WebBrowser control and I want to show to users when is loading a page. I've used events:

```
private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is in the `navigated` event - this

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx)

> Occurs when the WebBrowser control has navigated to a new document and has begun loading it.

This obviously could be long before the document is actually rendered.

I'm not sure there's any event to use to determine when the page is fully loaded and is rendered.

In iron7, I detect when the editor is loaded by using a timer - that timer keeps trying to call javascript methods in the script - I know these are only available after the document javascript `ready` occurs.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I've putted textbox outside of the screen, so I can't see it. It wasn't an event choice, it was a position error. My error. Sorry.

Comment: Excellent. Well done on fixing your own issue - looks like the non-transparent browser control strikes again!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `LoadCompleted` event:

```
private void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingText.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

This ensures that once everything is rendered the loading bar will disappear.

See the msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted(v=VS.92).aspx

(I think Stuart was looking at the Windows Forms implementation of WebBrowser rather than the Phone Control)

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I've putted textbox outside of the screen, so I can't see it. It wasn't an event choice, it was a position error. My error. Sorry.

Comment: Great - glad you figured it out.